# Awslogs state file keeps getting corrupt

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

The logs I have configured to be sent to cloudwatch are not being sent consistently. I looked at the awslogs.log and saw the error:

```
2020-01-30 03:30:03,193 - cwlogs.push.publisher - WARNING - 15309 - Thread-7 - Caught exception: An error occurred (DataAlreadyAcceptedException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation: The given batch of log events has already been accepted. The next batch can be sent with sequenceToken: 49600022193738425501694334465203795414139396777243338018
```

I did some research online and found that the /var/lib/awslogs/agent-state file is corrupt. When I delete the file the logs successfully go to cloudwatch BUT the file continuously breaks and I have to delete the state file. Would anyone know why this state file keeps getting corrupt? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have multiple processes/instances writing to the same log group?

Comment: Yes I do, we have 2 servers that do the same thing, which have the same logs. should I seperate them and put them in their own log groups?

Comment: Yes both servers are writing to the same log group

Comment: Actually sharing a log group shouldn't be an issue. It's sharing a log stream that's problematic.

Comment: Yea they arent sharing the same log stream. its still a mystery as to why they just stop feeding the logs back.